# Cannot connect to POP3 on Dovecot

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, dovecot

I installed Postfix and Dovecot on Ubuntu 18.04. I tested sending and receiving emails via telnet. Everything works from localhost. This is a droplet on DigitalOcean.

From any remote system, I can telnet to this instance on port 25 but not on 110. This is strange. I can telnet to 110 from the instance itself. Firewall is disabled.

This is the netstat result:

```
**netstat -anp4 |grep dove**
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24503/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:143           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24503/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24503/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24503/dovecot
```

From the remote, I get:

```
Trying 123.123.123.12...
```

for 60 seconds and then a timeout message.

Comment: Posting any config changes to configs from stock would help with diagnosis.

Comment: No, didn't change anything in the dovecot config files.

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot defaults to requiring SSL/TLS for all remote logins. If you must use unsecured logins like telnet (or for testing) you must modify /etc/dovecot/10-auth.conf to:

`disable_plaintext_auth = no`

and modify /etc/dovecot/10-ssl.conf:

`ssl = no`

then restart Dovecot.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately, didn't work. I made the changes to both files and restarted. Same result. If Dovecot is waiting for AUTH banner, shouldn't the connection on the port get established instead of this timeout?

Comment: Only thing I can think of now is DO (or someone like your ISP) is blocking ports